# Reduce space after title once

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I want to **reduce the space** after my `\section`, which is nothing new. There exist questions and the answer is: `\titlespacing*`

But how can I do it **just once** after one section headline?

Comment: You can limit the scope of `\titlespacing*` by wrapping it inside a group. Or, you can just issue `\vspace{<len>}` after `\section` (where `<len>` is a negative length). Have you tried any of these? Consistency should be what you're after though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Werner* said in his comment, `\vspace{<len>}` ( `<len>` negative) solves this problem.